# sysctl setting for maximum connections from ip address

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, sysctl

Is there any settings in sysctl that controls the maximum number of connections that are allowed from any one ip address? I'm having connection issues a redis server and a rabbitmq instance and I'd like to eliminate this possible condition before delving deeper into netstat results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux there are sysctl settings given and explained.

See http://fasterdata.es.net/fasterdata/host-tuning/linux/ for some other tunables.